# node-sass watch and compile to a single file

Tags: css, node.js

I am a bit new to sass, but I am starting a new project and figured why not dive in and learn as I go! So my question is this...

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
/sass
-->bootstrap
-->theme
-->_bootstrap.scss
-->_theme.scss
```

I want to be able to set npm-sass to watch for changes to any the entire directory (including bootstrap) and compile the sass into a single file located at:

```
/css/theme.min.css
```

I know that the `-w sets` the watch, and that `--output-style compressed` does the job of minifying, but how would i set this to watch the directory and only compile a single file?

Hopefully I asked the question well enough :)

Comment: are you using any build tools like grunt or gulp ?

Comment: no grunt or gulp are also new to me!

Comment: can you try this - `node-sass --watch=sass --output-style=compressed--source-map="/css/theme.min.css" --recursive sass/_theme.scss -o build`

Comment: does not appear to be working for me

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the files, Sass does not support directory compiling since the order of importing is important.

```
@import "_bootstrap.scss";
@import "_theme.scss";
```

You want your own custom theme to overwrite the bootstrap styling. You can also import files that have imports in it.

Comment: Im not sure how this is helping OP's question.

Comment: He wants to compile the whole directory, but you have to explicitly say what to compile by importing it into one file. That file will be compiled and minified, whatever you want.

Comment: right my _theme.scss has @import "_bootstrap.scss" got that! what i am trying to do is watch for changes in the entire directory and if there are changes compile sass/_theme.scss to css/theme.min.css

Comment: And here you can see the command: https://github.com/sass/node-sass#command-line-interface . Maybe the -r command can help you as well, keep in mind that you have your output file in a different directory since it can come in a unlimited recursive loop.

Comment: Example: Watch the sass directory for changes, compile with sourcemaps to the css directory
  node-sass --watch --recursive --output css
    --source-map true --source-map-contents sass

Comment: If OP is as absent-minded as I am, than this answer is actually helpful. If you use the `--watch` option, both `theme.css` and `bootstrap.css` will be compiled separately because bootstrap.scss doesn't have an underscore: `_bootstrap.scss`

Answer (score 0):

I am launching **node-sass** from a js file. My file is called **actions.js** and before editing any scss file I am opening a console in the root folder and running:

```
node actions.js
```

Below the contents of **actions.js**:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawnSync;

const watchFolder = './assets/scss';
const mainFile = 'assets/scss/main.scss';
const outFolder = 'assets/css';

console.log(`Watching for file changes on ${watchFolder}`);

fs.watch(watchFolder, (event, filename) => {
  if (filename) {
        console.log(`${filename} file Changed`);
        spawn('cmd.exe', [`/c node-sass ${mainFile} -o ${outFolder}`]);
   }
});
```